# Send asynchronous post request with asynchttpclient as a maven project and run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am completely loosing my mind here. This is the first time I use java and its all very scary to me.

Anyway, What I need to do is create a small java maven project where I listen to a specific UDP port (python script atm, emulating the device that I should be using), and then some stuff before sending a post request to a specific url with two post arguments.

I found this https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client library that seems to be getting good reviews and reputation.

What have I accomplished so far?

1. I have managed to create a maven project (obviously)
2. Wrote the receiver class (works perfectly!) - The class that catches the UDP message and stores whatever need to be stored to be used later when sending the POST message.
3. Wrote the code responsible for sending a POST message using the library (I am not sure it works tbh since I could not run it):

> ```
>     // To make post request to send data
>   AsyncHttpClient client = Dsl.asyncHttpClient();
>
>   BoundRequestBuilder postRequest = client
>           .preparePost("http://localhost:8080/my_custom_url/")
>           .addFormParam("id", myid)
>           .addFormParam("stream", inData);
>
>   // Asynchronous execution
>   postRequest.execute(new AsyncHandler<Object>() {
>       public State onStatusReceived(HttpResponseStatus responseStatus) throws Exception {
>           System.out.print("\nstatus received");
>           return null;
>       }
>
>       public State onHeadersReceived(HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
>           System.out.print("\nheaders received");
>           return null;
>       }
>
>       public State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
>           System.out.print("\nbody part received");
>           return null;
>       }
>
>       public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
>
>       }
>
>       public Object onCompleted() throws Exception {
>           System.out.print("\nexecute completed");
>           return null;
>       }
>   });
>
>   // Close to stop memory leaks after we are done
>   try {           client.close();         } catch (IOException e) {           infoBox("Could not close AsyncHttpClient.", "Error");
>       System.exit(0);         }
> ```

4. Built the maven project (From within eclipse) by doing: pom.xml > Right Click > Run As > Maven Build ... > Goal set as 'package'

> ```
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [INFO]                                                                         
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Building MyProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyProject ---
> [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\me\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\src\main\resources
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MyProject ---
> [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MyProject ---
> [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\me\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\src\test\resources
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MyProject ---
> [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ MyProject ---
> [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\me\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\target\surefire-reports
> -------------------------------------------------------
>  T E S T S
> -------------------------------------------------------
> Running me.company.MyProject.AppTest
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
> Results :
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ MyProject ---
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 1.044 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-21T13:23:49+03:00
> [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

5. Tried running through powershell doing the following:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\me\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\target> java -cp .\MyProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar me.company.MyProject.App
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/asynchttpclient/AsyncHandler
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHandler
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 7 more
> ```

Would appreciate any help regarding this. Happy to provide more information when needed.

Comment: You need to include the http lib in the classpath too. Now it contains only your jar.

Comment: you also need to add your dependencies to cp so it can find it. maven does this for you, but running it with java you need to do explicit

Comment: You can create an executable jar with maven. You can find this helpful https://jinahya.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/executable-jar-with-apache-maven/

Comment: @HenningLuther I am not sure what you mean by that, can you please guide me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: the classpath you are configuring with -cp is only containing your own artifact, but not the dependecy of http, you have to add it too. maven adds all dependencies defined in the pom to the classpath, thats why its working with maven.